# Form Validation not happening on angular 2 for input type="file"

Tags: forms, angular

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fileName">Name</label>

    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileName"  placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xlsx, .xls"
           required
           [(ngModel)]="model.fileName" name="fileName"
           #fileName="ngModel">
    <div [hidden]="fileName.valid || fileName.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
      File to be uploaded is required
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using angularjs2 forms, I am trying to upload a file and submit the form. Even if I choose the file, the control doesn't recognize the selected value.

Comment: elaborate a bit.?What do you mean by "Even if I choose the file, the control doesn't recognize the selected value."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 File upload from input type=file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399617/angular-2-file-upload-from-input-type-file)

Comment: `input type=file` is not supported by Angular directly AFAIR

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938495/5413117) for a full working example + explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others stated, input type=file is not supported (yet?) by Angular. You have some workaround

```
//template
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileName"  placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xlsx, .xls"
           required
           (change)="onImageChangeFromFile($event)">

//component
onImageChangeFromFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      //validation here then attribute the value to your model
      this.model = file
    }
  }
```

Comment: This has worked for me. I was able to put a save button and then use the value of this.model to post to my api.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form >
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileName"  placeholder="Upload 
    file" accept=".txt"required  (change)="onImageChangeFromFile($event)">
 </form>

onImageChangeFromFile(event)
{

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
        if(file.type == "text/plain") {
          console.log(file.type);
          alert("this is text file");

        }
        else {
           alert("please fill right file");
        }
    }
}
```