# Using reactive form validation with <input type="file"> for an Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing a component with a file picker that uploads a file to our CDN. I'm trying to add a reactive form on this component to validate the image input, so I can check against file name/extension etc, and keep it wrapped it in a form so I can keep the benefits of Angulars validation.

My component HTML is

```
<form class="mt-4" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-file">Browse
       <input name="file" type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" formControlName="imageInput"
    </label>

    <p *ngIf="file" class="pl-4 align-middle mb-0">{{file.name}}</p>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And my component code behind is

```
onChange(event: EventTarget) {
  // file picker code

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      imageInput: [this.file.name, CustomValidators.imageValidator]
  });
}
```

The `CustomValidars.imageValidator` only just logs the input at the minute.

When the component is loaded, the error message displays as `ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

Basically, I want to use the file input in my reactive form, so I can validate against the filename.

Comment: This issue is still probably open: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3466

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938495/5413117) for a full working example + explanation

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As @ibrahim mention it's not implemented yet, but i got the same problem and solved it using `hidden` field. on `onFileChange` method set `file.name` to `hidden` field, where you can validate.

```
   <form class="mt-4" [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-file">Browse
           <input name="file" type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
           <input type="hidden" name="fileHidden" formControlName="imageInput"/> <!-- Validation Field -->
        </label>

        <p *ngIf="file" class="pl-4 align-middle mb-0">{{file.name}}</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
    </form>



onFileChange($event) {
     let file = $event.target.files[0]; // <--- File Object for future use.
     this.form.controls['imageInput'].setValue(file ? file.name : ''); // <-- Set Value for Validation
}
fileName = '';
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      imageInput: [fileName, Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: Nice solution (I also added the file file input as a control so that I could add validation messages)

Comment: no databinding solutions included with existing files.

Answer (score 3):

```js
export class myClass implements OnInit {

  myForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    myFile: new FormControl('')
  })

  onFileChange($event) {

    this.myForm.patchValue({
      myFile: $event.target.files[0]
    })
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```

Comment: Add some context of answer.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `<input type="file">` is read-only, You need to set the option `emitModelToViewChange:false` when calling `setValue()` to avoid that error :

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

SOLUTION :

```
this.form.get('<name>').setValue(file, {emitModelToViewChange: false});
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `formControlName="imageInput"` from your <input type="file" and this will solve your problem.