# How to set file object in state with React hooks?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, react-hooks

I want to add to state and file object which I'm getting from input type file, and my problem is that I cannot update state with this:

```
currentTarget.files[0]
```

I'm getting this error:

> DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

```
const [data, changeData] = useState({
  name: '',
  surname: '',
  cv: '',
});
```

HandleChangeEvent for getting data

```
const handleChangeData = ({ currentTarget }, key) => {
    if (currentTarget.type === 'file') {
      const files = currentTarget.files[0];
      changeData((prevState) => {
        console.log(prevState);
        return { ...prevState, [key]: files };
      });
    } else {
      // Validate property
      const val = currentTarget.value;
      const errorMessage = validateProperty(currentTarget);
      if (errorMessage) errors[currentTarget.name] = errorMessage;
      else delete errors[currentTarget.name];

      changeData((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, [key]: val };
      });
    }
  };
```

I want to get property `files` from input field and send it to backend

Comment: try using event.target.files[0] instead of currentTarget

Comment: I was trying, getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass a 'value' prop to the file input.

`<input type="file" value="???" />`

In `React` (as well as in `html/js`) file inputs values can only be set by a user, and not programmatically (due to security reasons).

You should work with your file input as with an `uncontrolled component`

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag

---

**Solution**: Set the state's value from the file input (if you really need it), but don't set the input's value from state. Just find another way to show that the file has already been chosen in UI.

Answer (score 1):

@chumakoff answer provide a good solution, but it worth noting, this has nothing to do with react. It is how the browser works.

You added only part of your code, so I assume you are trying to create a hook for setting value and change handler, just like you'll do with the default  `<input type="text"/>`.

However, `<input type="file"/>` work differently - only the user can set it's value (e.i. the **file object** and the **file name**) for security reasons. As the error suggest, the only thing you can set this value to is - an empty string.

See [this question about Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970970/angular-5-file-upload-failed-to-set-the-value-property-on-htmlinputelement), which produce the same error.

Answer (score -5):

```
changeData(
    { 
        ...data, 
        [key]: val 
    }
);
```

**EDIT:** *cause of comment*

As my grandpa say: "*RTFM*"

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

I don't want to copy paste the doc

Comment: A good answer should provide an explanation rather than a piece of code. try to explain what led you to write this code and how it would help face the issue.