# Modifying file input attachment using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working in a proprietary CMS where I only have HTML + Javascript/jQuery access and am using their automatically generated form.  I am trying to add the ability to crop images to this form using cropper.js.  I have written a script to take the file uploaded and load it into cropper.  I am looking for a workaround to attach this file back to the original hidden field generated by the CMS.  When I try to set the value of the hidden file, I get the message "Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."

Here is a snippet of my code which produces the error

```
$("#crop-image").click(function() {
    var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    document.querySelector('.upload-container').appendChild(canvas);
    var blob = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(typeof blob);
    console.log(blob);
    const hiddenInput = document.getElementById("signup_signup_profile_attributes_image");
    hiddenInput.value = blob;
})
```

Anyone have an idea of how to get this method to work or another workaround to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I googled the error message and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970970/angular-5-file-upload-failed-to-set-the-value-property-on-htmlinputelement).

Comment: you can't set file inputs. you can use ajax to spoof a file upload from a blob or dataURL...