# how to validate file control on file upload on angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn angular 5. In a create form there is a file field

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" formControlName = "fileInput" fileInput >
<div *ngIf="angForm.controls.fileInput.sizeinvalid && (angForm.controls.fileInput.dirty || angForm.controls.fileInput.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls.fileInput.errors.invalid">Maximum allowed image Size is 5 MB</div>
</div>
```

and I have create a customValidator class and registered in module. To initiate the validator on change I have added @HostListener

```
@Directive({
   selector: "[fileInput]",
   providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: FileValidator, multi: true },
  ]
})
export class FileValidator implements Validator {
   constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
   @HostListener('change', ['$event.target']) onChange(target) {
       this.validate(this.el.nativeElement);      
   }

   static validate(c: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
      if (c.size > 0) {
         console.log("Maximum size")
         return { "sizeinvalid" : true};
      } else {
         console.log('No size');
         return null;
      }       
   }

   validate(c: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
      return FileValidator.validate(c);
   }
}
```

But, the code is not getting me any validation errors. Please figure out corrections needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the solution by adding **registerOnChange** for the file control. Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889384/angular2-validation-for-input-type-file-wont-trigger-when-changing-the-fi/41938495#41938495), to find the solution that I have opted.